# Let $C$ be a path from $(0,0)$ to $(2,1)$ find $\int_C ydx + xy dy$ over $x=2y^2$ and the straight line

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

So I need to integrate (Using Greens Theorem) $\int_C ydx + xy dy$ over $x=2y^2$ and the straight line along the given path $C$ from $(0,0)$ to $(2,1)$

(a) $x=2y^2$

(b) the straight line path which is $x=2y$, right?

So using Greens Theorem $P(x,y)=y$ and $Q(x,y)=xy$ thus $Q_x-P_y=y-1$

Thus

$$\int_C ydx + xy dy= \int \int y-1 dx dy$$

But I thought for (a) the integration was dx dy where the $x$ bounds are $0$ to $2y^2$ and $y$ bounds from $0$ to $1$ but this doesn't give me the desired answer. Where am I going wrong in choosing the bounds and order of integration?

BTW this is not for homework, Im TAing for Calc III and took it back in 2009 so I forgot a lot of stuff so I'm self teaching myself the material over again as the class goes. I don't need the answer, just a comment on what the bounds and order of integration would be and why.

Comment: This is not a Green's theorem problem because the question asks for the integral over the two different paths only. You would set up the line integrals normally

Comment: By Green's theorem, the double integral over a region equals the line integral around the boundary curve enclosing that region. If you draw the region $\{(x,y) : 0\leq x\leq 2y^2, \ 0\leq y \leq 1\}$, you'll see that $C$ does not enclose the region, it's only one part of the boundary curve. To find the line integral over $C$, you'll need to subtract the line integrals over the other parts of the boundary.

Comment: To be more precise, if $C_1$ is the curve from $(2,1)$ to $(2,0)$, and $C_2$ is the curve from $(2,0)$ to $(0,0)$, Green's theorem tells you that the double integral you computed equals $$\int_{C} +\int_{C_1}+\int_{C_2}$$

Notice how I chose the orientation of $C_1$ and $C_2$ to be consistent with that of $C$.

Comment: The bounds you've set up for the double integral are correct, I suspect that this is the part you're missing. Either way, it's not very efficient to use Green's theorem here, since you'll wind up calculating two line integrals and a double integral, as opposed to just one line integral.